# Sort 2D array with selection-sort method and write the result to the file

Tags: java, c#, php, python, selection-sort

I have a task to do and I am a little stuck.
I have to order some arrays from a file with 'selection sort' method and write the solution to the end of the file.
For example:

```
file.txt
9 3 1 12 8 6
22 3 1 8
78 61 19 5 99
```

is given. After sorting I should have something like that:

```
file.txt
9 3 1 12 8 6
22 3 1 8
78 61 19 5 99
----sorted----
1 3 6 8 9 12
1 3 8 22
5 19 61 78 99
```

I have to mention that I have to do it in PHP, Java, C# and Python.
I started coding it in PHP but I'm a little stuck. My code looks like this:

```
<?php

function selectionSort(array $array) {
    $length = count($array);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $min = $i;
        for($j = $i + 1; $j < $length; $j ++) {
            if ($array[$j] < $array[$min]) {
                $min = $j;
            }
        }
        $tmp = $array[$min];
        $array[$min] = $array[$i];
        $array[$i] = $tmp;
    }
    return $array;
}

//CREATE ARRAYS FROM FILE LINES:
$file_handle = fopen("fisier.txt", "r+");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
    $parts_sorted = selectionSort($parts);
     for ($n=0; $n<count($parts_sorted); $n++){
        echo $parts_sorted[$n]." ";
    }

    echo "<br>";

}
fclose($file_handle);
```

The problem here is that it doesn't sort well, I mean my txt file is

```
9 12 5 4 13 8
3 7 12 44 22 4 13
70 1 12 55 34
22 13 7 50 3 1 9 14 27 77
56 2 9 45 35 12 7 63
```

and the result from the php code is

```
4 5 8 9 12 13
13 3 4 7 12 22 44
1 12 34 55 70
1 3 7 77 9 13 14 22 27 50
2 7 9 12 35 45 56 63
```

which is not a good sort. Can you tell why?
Do you know what should I do next to write the sorted arrays to the end of the file?
And a little help for java,c# and python would be great. Sorry for the long post but I am a noob here. Thank you!

Comment: Why `java`, `c#` and `python` tag!!!

Comment: Probably because of "I have to do it in PHP, Java, C# and Python".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets() returns the linefeed/carriage-return character that ends the line
So you're not comparing `13` to something but `13\r\n` or `13\n` or ....

You can either do something like

```
$line_of_text = trim(fgets($file_handle));
```

to get rid of any leading/trailing whitespace of the line read from the file and/or

```
$parts = array_map('intval', explode(' ', $line_of_text));
```

to convert [every](http://docs.php.net/array_map) element [to an integer](http://docs.php.net/intval).

(In case all elements are within the value range of a php integer, I advise using the array_map/intval thingy as the comparision of numers *as number* is apparently what you want. Otherwise you *might* be interested in [strnatcmp()](http://docs.php.net/strnatcmp) as your comparision function instead of the < operator)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short Java snippet.

What it does

- read the file `file.txt` line by line
- convert the values of a line into integer values
- sort the integer values using method `selectionSort(int[])`
- write the sorted values back to file `file_sorted.txt`

.

```
// equal to your PHP implementation
static void selectionSort(int[] ints) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ints.length; j++) {
            if (ints[j] < ints[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = ints[min];
        ints[min] = ints[i];
        ints[i] = temp;
    }
}

...

Path fileIn = Paths.get("file.txt");
Path fileOut = Paths.get("file_sorted.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(fileIn);
        BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(fileOut,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
    for (String l = br.readLine(); l != null; l = br.readLine()) {
        String[] fields = l.split(" +");
        int[] ints = Arrays.asList(fields) // convert to List
                // convert the List into a Stream
                .stream()
                // map the entries to their integer values
                .mapToInt(f -> Integer.valueOf(f))
                // convert the stream to an array
                .toArray();
        selectionSort(ints);
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            bw.append(Integer.toString(ints[i]));
            if (i < ints.length - 1) {
                bw.append(' ');
            }
        }
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

input `file.txt`

```
9 12 5 4 13 8
3 7 12 44 22 4 13
70 1 12 55 34
22 13 7 50 3 1 9 14 27 77
56 2 9 45 35 12 7 63
```

output `file_sorted.txt`

```
4 5 8 9 12 13
3 4 7 12 13 22 44
1 12 34 55 70
1 3 7 9 13 14 22 27 50 77
2 7 9 12 35 45 56 63
```

Comment: As I understand the question an integral part of the task is to implement and use the [selection-sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), a typical undergraduate computer science topic.

Comment: @VolkerK After reading the question again. I agree with you the problem is not related to the sorting. I have updated my answer to provide a Java snippet similar to the PHP example from the OP. As you mention the problem is not in the sorting function of the OP.

Comment: Really nice, thank you! But the idea is to use the same file, to write the output to the end of the input file. Is it enough if I modify your code with something like
BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(fileIn..
but use a certain flag if exists so it doesn't overwrite the file, but to write at the end of it?

Comment: @Andrew No this wouldn't work as expected. You might first read all lines into an array `Files.readAllLines(fileIn)` and process the lines from that array. To append the sorted lines to the input file you could use `Files.newBufferedWriter(fileIn, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)`.